# Why is my app crashing when I try to implement my bottom navigation bar in Flutter?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, navigation

I am trying to implement a `bottomNavigationBar` that goes to different pages. So far, I have made the bulk of everything, which you can see in my code below.

Here is my `bottomNavigationBar` code in `navBar.dart`:

```
// ignore: file_names
import 'package:bottom_navy_bar/bottom_navy_bar.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../views/home_page.dart';
import '../views/secondScreen.dart';

// ignore: camel_case_types
class navBar extends StatefulWidget {
  const navBar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<navBar> createState() => _navBarState();
}

// ignore: camel_case_types
class _navBarState extends State<navBar> {
  int currentIndex = 0;
  final screens = [
    const HomePage(),
    const SecondRoute(),
    const SecondRoute(),
    const SecondRoute(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    screens[currentIndex];
    return BottomNavyBar(
      animationDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 260),
      curve: Curves.ease,
      showElevation: false,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
      selectedIndex: currentIndex,
      onItemSelected: (index) {
        setState(() {
          currentIndex = index;
        });
        // Push the new page onto the navigation stack
        // Navigator.push(
        //   context,
        //   MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => pages[index]),
        // );
      },
      items: <BottomNavyBarItem>[
        BottomNavyBarItem(
          inactiveColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 20, 143, 199),
          activeColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 5, 176, 255),
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          icon: const Icon(Icons.home),
          title: const Text('Home'),
        ),
        BottomNavyBarItem(
          inactiveColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 20, 143, 199),
          activeColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 5, 176, 255),
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          icon: const Icon(Icons.discord),
          title: const Text('Discord'),
        ),
        BottomNavyBarItem(
          inactiveColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 20, 143, 199),
          activeColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 5, 176, 255),
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          icon: const Icon(Icons.school),
          title: const Text('Examotron'),
        ),
        BottomNavyBarItem(
          inactiveColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 20, 143, 199),
          activeColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 5, 176, 255),
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          icon: const Icon(Icons.document_scanner),
          title: const Text('Notes'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

And here is my home page `home_page.dart`:

```
import 'package:xconcordia/services/remote_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:xconcordia/views/secondScreen.dart';
import 'package:xconcordia/widgets/categoryPicker.dart';
import '../widgets/libraryCards.dart';
import '../widgets/libraryStatsHeader.dart';
import '../widgets/navBar.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

var webb = '';
String webOccupancy = '';
String greyOccupancy = '';
String vannierOccupancy = '';
String libTime = '';
String webLevel = '';
String greyLevel = '';
String vannierLevel = '';

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  bool isLoading = false;
  int currentIndex = 1;

  // List of pages
  List<Widget> pages = [
    const HomePage(),
    const SecondRoute(),
    const SecondRoute(),
    const SecondRoute(),
  ];
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _fetchWebOccupancy();
    _fetchVannierOccupancy();
    _fetchGreyOccupancy();
    _fetchLibTime();
  }

  Future<void> _fetchLibTime() async {
    if (libTime == '') {
      String? libraryTime = await getDataAPI_time().getPosts();
      setState(() {
        libTime = libraryTime.toString();
      });
    }
  }

  Future<void> _fetchWebOccupancy() async {
    if (webOccupancy == '') {
      String? occupancy = await getDataAPI().getPosts();
      setState(() {
        webOccupancy = occupancy!.substring(0, occupancy.length - 5);
        if (webOccupancy == '' || int.parse(webOccupancy) < 0) {
          webOccupancy = '0';
        }
        if (int.parse(webOccupancy) > 100) {
          webLevel = 'High';
        } else if (int.parse(webOccupancy) > 75 &&
            int.parse(webOccupancy) < 100) {
          webLevel = 'Medium';
        } else {
          webLevel = 'Low';
        }
        isLoading = false;
      });
    }
  }

  Future<void> _fetchGreyOccupancy() async {
    if (greyOccupancy == '') {
      String? occupancy = await getDataAPI_G().getPosts();
      setState(() {
        greyOccupancy = occupancy!.substring(0, occupancy.length - 5);
        if (greyOccupancy == '' || int.parse(greyOccupancy) < 0) {
          greyOccupancy = '0';
        }
        if (int.parse(greyOccupancy) > 100) {
          greyLevel = 'High';
        } else if (int.parse(greyOccupancy) > 50 &&
            int.parse(greyOccupancy) < 100) {
          greyLevel = 'Medium';
        } else {
          greyLevel = 'Low';
        }
        isLoading = false;
      });
    }
  }

  Future<void> _fetchVannierOccupancy() async {
    if (vannierOccupancy == '') {
      String? occupancy = await getDataAPI_V().getPosts();
      setState(() {
        vannierOccupancy = occupancy!.substring(0, occupancy.length - 5);
        if (vannierOccupancy == '' || int.parse(vannierOccupancy) < 0) {
          vannierOccupancy = '0';
        }
        if (int.parse(vannierOccupancy) > 100) {
          vannierLevel = 'High';
        } else if (int.parse(vannierOccupancy) > 50 &&
            int.parse(vannierOccupancy) < 100) {
          vannierLevel = 'Medium';
        } else {
          vannierLevel = 'Low';
        }
        isLoading = false;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        // elevation: 15,
        // leading: IconButton(
        //   icon: const Icon(Icons.menu),
        //   onPressed: () {},
        // ),

        title: const Text('xConcordia'),
        flexibleSpace: Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Color.fromARGB(223, 57, 25, 163),
                offset: Offset(0, 0),
                blurRadius: 20,
              ),
            ],
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.topLeft,
              end: Alignment.bottomRight,
              colors: [Colors.blue, Colors.purple],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: isLoading
          ? const Center(
              child: LinearProgressIndicator(
              color: Color.fromARGB(162, 114, 68, 251),
            ))
          : Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  // ignore: prefer_const_constructors
                  LibraryStatsHeader(), //LibraryStatsHeader widget is in a file called libraryStatsHeader
                  const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10)),
                  libCards(), //libCards widget is in a file called libraryCards
                  const categoryPicker(), //category picker
                ],
              ),
            ),
      bottomNavigationBar: const navBar(),
    );
  }
}
```

The issue in the above code is, despite my nav bar working (as in, clicking it changes the nav bar icons), the page state does not change (i.e, it doesn't go to another page, stays on the current page)

Now, I realize that I'm not doing anything with my screens [] array, so I should use that, and so in my `navBar.dart`, I thought to return `body: screens[currentIndex]` to make this logic work, so my nav bar is functional.

So, in this `navBar.dart` file, I surrounded the return with a `Scaffold` and did just that:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
      body: screens[currentIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavyBar(
        animationDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
        curve: Curves.ease,
        showElevation: false,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        selectedIndex: currentIndex,
        onItemSelected: (index) {
          setState(() {
            currentIndex = index;
          });
          // Push the new page onto the navigation stack
          // Navigator.push(
          //   context,
          //   MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => pages[index]),
          // );
        },
        items: <BottomNavyBarItem>[
          BottomNavyBarItem(
            inactiveColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 20, 143, 199),
            activeColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 5, 176, 255),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            icon: const Icon(Icons.home),
            title: const Text('Home'),
          ),
          BottomNavyBarItem(
            inactiveColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 20, 143, 199),
            activeColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 5, 176, 255),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            icon: const Icon(Icons.discord),
            title: const Text('Discord'),
          ),
          BottomNavyBarItem(
            inactiveColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 20, 143, 199),
            activeColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 5, 176, 255),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            icon: const Icon(Icons.school),
            title: const Text('Examotron'),
          ),
          BottomNavyBarItem(
            inactiveColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 20, 143, 199),
            activeColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 5, 176, 255),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            icon: const Icon(Icons.document_scanner),
            title: const Text('Notes'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Doing this, I get an infinite loop of the same error:

[image: Error]

What is flawed in my logic when I try to return the `Scaffold` with the `screens[currentIndex]` as the body? Is it wrong? How else would I get this navigation bar working?

**EDIT**: I have added nav bar to my `main.dart` file, replacing `home: HomePage()` with `navBar()`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../widgets/navBar.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: navBar(),
    );
  }
}
```

Yet, I still get the same error.

Comment: You have added HomePage() inside your list of widgets. Maybe that's why you are getting the error.

Comment: @Md.KamrulAmin Removing it and replacing all of them with SecondScreen() causes the same issue. But, if I don't add homescreen, then how will nav bar know to go to the first screen (aka home) if I dont provide it as a screen? The home screen is a different file.

Comment: You are not getting it buddy. You have to place your navbar let's say main. When you click the navbar just change your scaffold body with any widget

Comment: @Md.KamrulAmin Thanks, I tried that however. See my new code edited on the bottom of the question. Is my new implementation wrong? As I still get the same error with the new suggestion. Now, with this, my screen app is just white.

Comment: Let me just do you are prototype from scratch and explain it to you. Give me a moment.

Comment: Ok doing it in your project. But i will just remove the future calls

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250727/discussion-between-usama-saleem-and-md-kamrul-amin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your homePage(), remove list of pages, currentIndex and bottom navBar.
Your homePage() should look like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

var webb = '';
String webOccupancy = '';
String greyOccupancy = '';
String vannierOccupancy = '';
String libTime = '';
String webLevel = '';
String greyLevel = '';
String vannierLevel = '';

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  bool isLoading = true;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _fetchWebOccupancy();
    _fetchVannierOccupancy();
    _fetchGreyOccupancy();
    _fetchLibTime();
  }

  Future<void> _fetchLibTime() async {
    if (libTime == '') {
      String? libraryTime = await getDataAPI_time().getPosts();
      setState(() {
        libTime = libraryTime.toString();
      });
    }
  }

  Future<void> _fetchWebOccupancy() async {
    if (webOccupancy == '') {
      String? occupancy = await getDataAPI().getPosts();
      setState(() {
        webOccupancy = occupancy!.substring(0, occupancy.length - 5);
        if (webOccupancy == '' || int.parse(webOccupancy) < 0) {
          webOccupancy = '0';
        }
        if (int.parse(webOccupancy) > 100) {
          webLevel = 'High';
        } else if (int.parse(webOccupancy) > 75 &&
            int.parse(webOccupancy) < 100) {
          webLevel = 'Medium';
        } else {
          webLevel = 'Low';
        }
        isLoading = false;
      });
    }
  }

  Future<void> _fetchGreyOccupancy() async {
    if (greyOccupancy == '') {
      String? occupancy = await getDataAPI_G().getPosts();
      setState(() {
        greyOccupancy = occupancy!.substring(0, occupancy.length - 5);
        if (greyOccupancy == '' || int.parse(greyOccupancy) < 0) {
          greyOccupancy = '0';
        }
        if (int.parse(greyOccupancy) > 100) {
          greyLevel = 'High';
        } else if (int.parse(greyOccupancy) > 50 &&
            int.parse(greyOccupancy) < 100) {
          greyLevel = 'Medium';
        } else {
          greyLevel = 'Low';
        }
        isLoading = false;
      });
    }
  }

  Future<void> _fetchVannierOccupancy() async {
    if (vannierOccupancy == '') {
      String? occupancy = await getDataAPI_V().getPosts();
      setState(() {
        vannierOccupancy = occupancy!.substring(0, occupancy.length - 5);
        if (vannierOccupancy == '' || int.parse(vannierOccupancy) < 0) {
          vannierOccupancy = '0';
        }
        if (int.parse(vannierOccupancy) > 100) {
          vannierLevel = 'High';
        } else if (int.parse(vannierOccupancy) > 50 &&
            int.parse(vannierOccupancy) < 100) {
          vannierLevel = 'Medium';
        } else {
          vannierLevel = 'Low';
        }
        isLoading = false;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        // elevation: 15,
        // leading: IconButton(
        //   icon: const Icon(Icons.menu),
        //   onPressed: () {},
        // ),

        title: const Text('xConcordia'),
        flexibleSpace: Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Color.fromARGB(223, 57, 25, 163),
                offset: Offset(0, 0),
                blurRadius: 20,
              ),
            ],
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.topLeft,
              end: Alignment.bottomRight,
              colors: [Colors.blue, Colors.purple],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: isLoading
          ? const Center(
          child: LinearProgressIndicator(
            color: Color.fromARGB(162, 114, 68, 251),
          ))
          : Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            // ignore: prefer_const_constructors
            LibraryStatsHeader(), //LibraryStatsHeader widget is in a file called libraryStatsHeader
            const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10)),
            libCards(), //libCards widget is in a file called libraryCards
            const categoryPicker(), //category picker
            
          ],
        ),
      ),
      
    );
  }
}
```

Do not add bottomNavigation to the list of pages like homePage(), secondRoute(), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Scaffold

```
return Scaffold(
  body: screens.elementAt(currentIndex),
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavyBar(
```

Remove bottomNavigationBar: const navBar() from homepage

Call navBar class in home of main.dart file as below

```
void main() {
runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 const MyApp({super.key});

// This widget is the root of your application.
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return const MaterialApp(
  title: 'Flutter Demo',
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  home: navBar(), <------ here
 );
}
}
```

Comment: Nope, putting this code instead causes the same error code.

Comment: Because you use bottom navigation bar in home page. Remove bottomNavigationBar: const navBar(), from home page and call navBar class in home of main.dart file

Comment: Right, but then how would I show the nav bar in the home page? I need it to be everywhere, I have to add it in the home page too, no?

Comment: Call navBar class in home: of main.dart file

Comment: Thanks, however, I edited the post with the new changes you recommend, as well as the same code as the Scaffold you recommended earlier. The same error. Now, my screen is white screen though.

Comment: What error you are getting in console when white screen display?

Comment: Same error: nother exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion:
line 4606 pos 14: 'owner!._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.

Comment: Have you removed bottom navigation bar from home page? as I mention in my answer